# Какой паттерн подобрать для отправки команд разным серверам и разным форматам?

Tags: ооп, php, шаблоны-проектирования

Приветствую всех. В ходе разработки одного модуля возник вопрос по красивой организации кода.
И так, у меня есть некий объект "Пользователь" который обращается к классу "репозиторий" содержащим всевозможные команды этого пользователя. Различные команды отправляются в разном формате (POST, GET, XML) и на разные сервера, так же ответы соответственно приходят в разных форматах. И сейчас у меня возникла трудность как сделать такую "фабрику", что бы можно было передать ей имя сервера и массив данных, а дальше она сама взяла настройки из соответствующего класса, отправила эти данные на нужный сервер и в зависимости от сервера обработала этот результат нужным парсером.
Может кто подсказать красивую диаграмму классов для такой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, если я правильно осознал вопрос, то вам может подойти "Команда" - [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%EE%EC%E0%ED%E4%E0_%28%F8%E0%E1%EB%EE%ED_%EF%F0%EE%E5%EA%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%FF%29)

Answer (score -1):

посмотри на реализацию класса Validator в YII  [вот тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/Validator.php)
От него можно оттолкнутся